# Lookup function in Spark using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

This is a Newbie Question.

In the Code below

```
val var_A=graphA.edges
                .filter{case(currEdge)=>currEdge.srcId==currEdge.dstId}
                .map{case(currEdge)=>(currEdge.srcId,currEdge.attr)}
```

`var_A` has a type `RDD[(graphx.VertexId,Double)]`

I want to create a Map using `graphx.VertexId` as key, but then I map have a large Dataset and I was trying to use "lookup" instead.

But when I use lookup on "var_A", then it shows me 
return type: `Seq[Double]` and Input/Key type: `graphX.VertexId`.

I am troubled with the return type which I expect to be `Double` rather than `Seq[Double]`. Please point out the error.

Then I made var_B:

`val var_B= var_A.zipWithUniqueId`

Now when I use look up on "var_B", I get 
return type: `Seq[Long]` and
Input/Key type: `(graphX.VertexId,Double)`.

I basically want to lookup with `graphX.VertexId` as Input/Key type and want `Double` as the return Type.

Also I am doing this because Map may not have fitted on the driver's memory, causing OOM exceptions perhaps. But Actually the maximum Tuples that I would have will be in the order of 10^4. So is actually Big to be stored in Memory and broadcasted in the cluster?

Comment: It would help if you shared example data and expected output.

Comment: But, its just a problem of datatypes and lookup function, I have specified those relevant things

Comment: That might be true, but without example data your code is  not reproducible.